# xpath, how to get outer div based on inner?

Tags: html, xml, dom, xpath

Here is a sample of my HTML:

```
<div>
<a class="id2342">jack d m</a>
 x1
</div>
```

Basically, how would I get both "jack d m" & "x1" ?

Here is the code I have so far which only gives me "jack d m"

```
$row = $xpath->query('//a[@class="id2342"]')->item(0)->nodeValue;
```

Comment: Never use images for code or markup; use text formatted as code.  Fixed for you this time.

Answer (score 1):

This XPath,

```
string(//a[@class="id2342"]/..)
```

will return the string value of the parent of the `a` element whose `@class` attribute is `id2342`:

```
jack d m
 x1
```

You can replace `string()` with `normalize-space()` to normalize the whitespace in the returned string and return

```
jack d m x1
```

as requested.